# Java automatic file getting from folder

Tags: java

I have a class which give me list of files in folder, but i must set path of this folder in variable File. I want to get list of filles from folder where my program is. How I can do that?

Comment: Can you provide what you have currently?

Comment: Do you want to know what the current working directory is, then list those files?

Comment: Instead of just asking how something can be done, show your effort so far to achieve what you're asking for first. A reasonable amount of effort expected before asking here (and you should show it), but I see none so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below line to get current folder in java

```
 String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

This code provides the path in which java file is places where code is running. It is platform/operating system independent. However,  access to system properties can be restricted by the Security Manager.

Comment: Welcome .Try putting some sample code to show that to have putted effort. Else people will downvote and you will not get answer and also lose reputation.